# How to get return value of tasks when using Task.WaitAll()

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, parallel-processing, task

I need to get the return value of multiple `Task<List<string>>` executed in parallel and merge them into a new `List<string>`.

This is what I have currently. As you can see in the fiddle, the tasks are being executed in parallel (execute time is about 1s). Problem is don't know how to get the returned value (a `List<string>` object) from each execution so I can merge them.

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/91YqkY

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var filters = new List<string>
        {
            "A", "B", "C"
        }

        ;
        var api = new API();
        var TaskList = new List<Task>();
        foreach (var f in filters)
        {
            var LastTask = new Task<List<String>>(() =>
            {
                return api.GetArray(f);
            }

            );
            LastTask.Start();
            TaskList.Add(LastTask);
        }

        Task.WaitAll(TaskList.ToArray());
        foreach (var t in TaskList)
        {
            // I need to get the List<string> returned in each GetArray and merge them
        }
    }
}

public class API
{
    public List<string> GetArray(string param)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        return new List<String>{
            param + "1",
            param + "2",
            param + "3",
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: I hate to be pedantic, but `Task`s aren't "executed in parallel" are they? They're executed asynchronously.  Also, you can take action based on the completion order, or continue one based on the completion of another.

Comment: You're right, but since after I start one task, the next thing I do is start the next one and so on. I allow myself to say that they are executed in parallel since total execution time is 1s and each task takes 1s to complete.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try to use the `SelectMany` method:

```
var result = TaskList.Select(t => t.Result)
                     .SelectMany(r => r)
                     .ToList();
```

Initially you project each element of the `TaskList`, which is a `TaskList<string>` object, to it's result which in your case is a `List<string>` and then using the `SelectMany` method you define a sequence of all the strings in the results of the tasks. Last but not least, you have to call the `ToList`, in order your query to be executed and to get as a result a `List<string>`.

**Update**

As Sergey correctly pointed out in his comment below, you have to redefine your `TaskList`.

```
var TaskList = new List<Task<List<string>>();
```

Comment: I keep reading about that Result property but I'm not getting it...
`'System.Threading.Tasks.Task' does not contain a definition for 'Result' and no extension method 'Result' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task' could be found (press F4 to add a using directive or assembly reference)`

Comment: In this particular case all tasks return a `Task<List<string>>`. The `Result` property of such a `Task` object is a `List<string>`. Generally speaking the `Result` property of `Task<T>` is a `T` object.

Comment: @emzero, please use the following definition of the local variable: `var TaskList = new List<Task<List<String>>>();`.

Comment: Oh you're right. I missed that. Thank you!

Comment: @SergeyBrunov good catch :) I will add it to my answer.

Comment: @Christos, thank you! Sure.

Comment: @emzero, it was nothing.